# SCCM - Collecting data from client PCs at interval

Tags: powershell, sccm

my team is tasked to collect some data from client PCs at a regular interval using SCCM. Below are some of the data required:

- Computer name
- Free disk space for C: drive
- A specific registry key's value
- File version for chrome.exe

We just need to keep a snapshot of the last reported value for each client PCs. The values need to co-relate to each other as we need to export it out as a table. Would like to seek help on how to achieve this, thanks.

Comment: Can you update the question with what you've tried so far

Comment: If you're looking at monitoring you might want to look at SCOM, on the other hand, not sure how this is related with PowerShell.

Comment: We created a PowerShell script and run it to gather the information we need. However, it is only a one-time execution and we need a way to collect the data constantly at interval. It would be best if we can even set individual interval for each property.

Comment: For SCOM, is it meant for client PCs? Cause I got the impression that SCOM is used for server monitoring.

Comment: so for clarification you do not want to use the inventory of sccm for this but want to run a script (or 4 scripts) and want to know how to run a script recurringly via sccm? Or do you want to know how to write into a single file concurrently without compromising integrity?

Comment: Hi if using the hardware or software inventory, I might have difficulties as the data collection interval should be as close to real time as possible. Thus, I want to know if it is possible to run a script (or 4 scripts) recurringly via SCCM?